# Receiving data from WebClient.UploadString

Tags: c#

I am trying to send/receive byte array of image from server to server.

I think i managed to send it but am unable to receive it.

Here is code for sending:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/ARGallery/AUploadImage/{appid}")]
public IActionResult AUploadImage(IFormFile file, int appid)
{
    try
    {
        // Korisnik prosledjuje fajl kroz browser
        // Taj fajl ima svoje ime
        // Bezbednosti radi proveravam ime fajla i prilagodjavam ga
        string filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
        filename = this.EnsureCorrectFilename(filename);
        //===============



        // Uzimam app model iz buffera
        ApplicationsModel am = Buffer.GetApplication(appid);

        // Proveravam da li je uspesno uzet model, ako nije uzimam direktno iz faljova
        if (am == null)
            am = ApplicationsModel.List().Where(a => a.ID == appid).FirstOrDefault();

        // Ako je posle svega neuspesno vracam gresku
        if (am == null)
            return View("Error", "Error loading application info!");


        byte[] imageInBytes = null;
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream());
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);
            imageInBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        using(var client = new WebClient())
        {
            return Json(client.UploadString("http://" + am.Name + "/ARGallery/AUploadImage/" + file.FileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(imageInBytes)));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

and here is receiving code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/ARGallery/AUploadImage/{filename}")]
public IActionResult AUploadImage(string bufferedImage, string filename)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bufferedImage));
        System.Drawing.Image myimg = Image.FromStream(ms);


        while(System.IO.File.Exists(GetPathAndFilename(filename)))
        {
            string extension = "";
            int br = filename.ToString().IndexOf('.');
            string ex = filename.ToString().Substring(br);
            if (ex == "jpeg")
                extension = filename.Substring(filename.Length - 5, 5);
            else
                extension = filename.Substring(filename.Length - 4, 4);

            // Dodajem na ostatak fajl name-a bez extensiona random karaktere i vracam extension nazad
            filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.Length - 4) + AR.Security.HashPW(Program.rnd.Next(1000).ToString()).Substring(0, 2) + extension;
        }

        //Cuvam original format slike u temp folder
        myimg.Save(GetPathAndFilename(filename));

        // Cuvam osiromaseni format slike u temp folder
        LowerQuality((Bitmap)myimg).Save(GetPathAndFilenameLQ(filename));

        // Vracam nazad link do slike na remote serveru (serveru aplikacije)
        return Json(filename);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I get "null" exception on line `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bufferedImage));`

EDIT:

Also what i have tried on sending app side is this but still same problem:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/ARGallery/AUploadImage/{appid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AUploadImage(IFormFile file, int appid)
{
    try
    {
        // Korisnik prosledjuje fajl kroz browser
        // Taj fajl ima svoje ime
        // Bezbednosti radi proveravam ime fajla i prilagodjavam ga
        string filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
        filename = this.EnsureCorrectFilename(filename);
        //===============



        // Uzimam app model iz buffera
        ApplicationsModel am = Buffer.GetApplication(appid);

        // Proveravam da li je uspesno uzet model, ako nije uzimam direktno iz faljova
        if (am == null)
            am = ApplicationsModel.List().Where(a => a.ID == appid).FirstOrDefault();

        // Ako je posle svega neuspesno vracam gresku
        if (am == null)
            return View("Error", "Error loading application info!");


        byte[] imageInBytes = null;
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream());
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);
            imageInBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }


        using(var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var options = new
            {
                bufferedImage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(imageInBytes),
                filename = file.FileName
            };

            HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync("http://" + am.Name + "/ARGallery/AUploadImage", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            return Json(await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: An image *isn't* a string. It's binary data. You should probably be using `UploadData` - or ideally, migrate to `HttpClient` which is a more modern API. (That may not be the cause of your immediate problem, but it will definitely prevent the code from working.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you check edit

Comment: You still appear to be assuming that image data is UTF-8-encoded text. It isn't.